# Making a custom bookmark editor in Word 2010 with C# Add-In

Tags: c#, word-2010

I am following this MSDN walk-through: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5eef9s6f.aspx

But I get an error for the line:

```
Document extendedDocument = Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(this.Application.ActiveDocument);
```

The error is a red underline on Application and reads:

```
'MyRibionAddin.MyRibbon does not contain a definition for 'Application' and no extension method 'Application' accepting a first argument of type 'MyRibionAddIn.MyRibbon' could be found ( are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replaced with

```
 Document extendedDocument = Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument);
```

and it works